# Debugging custom application settings in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, settings, application-settings

I've got a bit of a strange situation going on. I've created a very simple class as such.

```
[Serializable]
[SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)]
public class StockSyncCollection : ObservableCollection<StockSyncDatum>
{
}

public class StockSyncDatum
{
    public StockSyncDatum() { }

    public StockSyncDatum(int posStockId, int posStockCatalogueId, DateTime lastUpdated)
    {
        this.PosStockId = posStockId;
        this.PosStockCatalogueId = posStockCatalogueId;
        this.LastUpdated = lastUpdated;
    }

    public int PosStockId { get; set; }
    public int PosStockCatalogueId { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

I have then created a custom setting through the designer for which the generated code looks like this

```
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
public global::Sync.Config.StockSyncCollection StockSyncCollection {
    get {
        return ((global::Sync.Config.StockSyncCollection)(this["StockSyncCollection"]));
    }
    set {
        this["StockSyncCollection"] = value;
    }
}
```

However the problem I am running into is that later in my code (after adding some items to the collection) I will call

```
Settings.Default.Save();
```

But what happens is that only some subset of the items that have been added to the collection up until the point the save method is called is actually persisted. So for example, I might add 50 items but only 10 of them will be saved.

Now note that I am calling `Settings.Default.Save()` in a loop. My gut instinct is telling me that there is some sort of hash that is generated of the object that isn't being updated.

So what I am wondering is how the hell do you debug Application Settings in C# apps? I can see various events like `SettingsChanging` and `SettingsSaving` but I do not see an event for `SettingsSaveError` or similar.

Anyone have any idea what might be going on or how to debug this?

**EDIT: The loop code basically looks like this.**

```
foreach (var partition in stockTransfers.Partition(PartitionCount))
{
    IList<StockTransferContract> stockTransferContracts = partition.ToStockTransferContracts();

    //Do all the magic syncing stuff...        

    foreach (var item in stockTransferContracts)
        _StockSyncCollection.Add(new StockSyncDatum(posStockId, posStockCatalogueId, DateTime.UtcNow));


    Settings.Default.Save();

}
```

Keep in mind that I need to call save because I expect errors to occasionally arise and need to ensure that the previously "Sync'd" items are noted.

Comment: "_I am calling Settings.Default.Save() in a loop_" that sounds odd, can you show that code?

Comment: See above for example

Comment: Why do you need to update it on each iteration? Why can't you update the settings after the foreach loop, ie when all the adds have been completed? Also, are there multiple threads involved here?

Comment: I could, but it would mean that if there is an error in a subsequent loop those items added prior would not be committed to the sync list in the settings repository. No single thread...

Comment: Is the setting's scope set to `Application`? If yes then try changing it to `User`